# Prevent browser viewport from sticking to bottom when page height increases in runtime?

Tags: javascript, css

Modern browsers seem to have a feature where the viewport sticks to bottom when page height increases. What actually happens is that browser scrolls the viewport at the same rate as height being increased when initial position is at (or very close to) the bottom of the page. This results in appearance as if page is expanding upwards instead of downwards.

How can this feature be disabled for a certain page using CSS or JS, so that the page would always visually expand downwards?

This of course, also happens when added element's height is expanded animated. For this reason, if possible, I would want to avoid resetting scroll position afterwards to prevent visible jump. The demo of this "feature" (that seems to happen only within rare conditions) interacting with the viewport and drop animation can be observed in the gif below.

[image]

*I know there must be a way, otherwise every site with infinite scroll would suffer from an infinite loop. Counter argument: Chrome appears not to do this for containers that surpass certain height limit. So maybe infinite-scroll sites don't even bother addressing this in their sites.*

Comment: Do you have an example illustrating this? I don't recall having seen this kind of behaviour. Note however that recently some browsers (Chrome and Safari IIRC) have announced that they will try to keep the same position (in terms of content) shown, so that would explain the behaviour if you are adding content above the currently visible part rather than below. Not sure if that's in the current releases or for future ones though.

Comment: @jcaron I doubt that I would be able to create a fiddle due to iframes. But I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @jcaron Please check the fiddle provided in the answer by Gokhan Kurt below. It demonstrates the behavior in Chrome. Additionally I've observed that if the expanding element exceeds a certain height, Chrome stops sticking to bottom and uses scroll relative to top as normal again.

Comment: @jcaron Gif image added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that when you scroll to the bottom, and a piece of content gets added, you stay at the bottom? Because the solution for that is real simple:

#### Option 1

- Store the current scrolloffset to the top (eg how many px you've scrolled down)
- Add new content
- Set scrolloffset to the top to the stored value

*Those last two steps can be done so fast that the user wont notice.*

#### Option 2

*Not 100% sure this works, but i'm guessing it does:*

- When the visitor scroll to the bottom, *always* scroll them back 3px. This way, they're not at the bottom at the point where new content gets added, so the browser stays where it is.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of resetting scroll to a stored position. Primarily because the height expansion is animated in my case and the code would be complex because multiple elements are moved from one place to another forcing height to increase and decrease. I can't tell if the jumps would still be visible even if I would write the correct code for storing/resetting scroll position. If no other solution pops up, I would have to try this.

Comment: Your animation doesnt matter. You store the location, get the content, and after your start your animation you set the scrollTop to the stored value (maybe wait 10ms). All you need it to "unsticky" the view, after that to animation continues.

Comment: Do you mean just reading and setting `scrollTop` by JS, right after the height animation starts? I think it may do the trick. Now that you say it, maybe it's enough to just re-apply current `scrollTop` by JS before the animation even starts, in case this behavior is only triggered after user scrolls to bottom manually. It's really hard to track when the browser algorithm decides to do this, but all the times I can recall seeing this was after manual scroll. I will do some testing...

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. You could move the setScroll to various points (or multiple, it's lightweight, maybe various browsers require various timings).

Comment: I've run some tests. Re-setting window scroll before animation didn't do anything. But storing scroll `var scroll = window.getScroll();` and then re-applying it `window.scrollTo(scroll.x, scroll.y);` after animation has been started prevents this "feature" from occurring most of the time. I believe I've still seen it happening once during testing, probably because of timings of asynchronous execution of CSS animations. It's an ugly hack, but I'm glad you suggested it. So far it's the only applicable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0bq79kr/1). You can observe that in Chrome, the first container snaps to the bottom, while the other divs has a scroll relative to the top. In Firefox or IE 11, you cannot observe this behavior.

This happens when the top bound of the last element on a scroll container is above the top bound of the container. The browser decides that the last element is what the user is interested in and decides to stay in that position.

The last div doesn't snap to the bottom because the scroll happens relative to the top bound of the last element and the last element is growing.

If you want a different behavior, I would not suggest handling it with Javascript, but I would suggest changing your layout considering these rules. For example the last div should be the growing one, instead of the previous siblings of it.

Obligatory code:

```js
var div = document.querySelectorAll('.growing');
var height = 500;

setInterval(function(){
 height += 100; 
 div[0].style.height = height + 'px';
 div[1].style.height = height + 'px';
  div[2].style.height = height + 'px';
},1000);
```

```css
.start, .end{
  height: 110px;
}
.start{
  background: red;
}
.end{
  background: green;
}
.growing{
  background: yellow;
}
.cnt1,.cnt2,.cnt3{
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px 0;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
}
.cnt1{
  height: 100px;
}

.cnt2{
  height: 120px;
}

.cnt3{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt1">
  <div class="start"></div>
  <div class="growing"></div>
  <div class="end"></div>
</div>
<div class="cnt2">
  <div class="start"></div>
  <div class="growing"></div>
  <div class="end"></div>
</div>

<div class="cnt3">
  <div class="start"></div>
  <div class="end"></div>
  <div class="growing">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** 
If the bounds of the growing div is in the visible area, the scroll is relative to the top of the growing div. So you can hack CSS to show the growing div, but actually not show it.

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6gsys8v/1/) I have used two different CSS hacks. First one is adding a negative margin bottom and a positive padding bottom at same amount. The second hack is adding an :after element to the growing div but hide its visibility.

Comment: Thank you for creating an example with reproducible behavior. I've been able to observe this in your fiddle an I'm now able to reproduce this more frequently in my dev case. In my case it's not possible to change the layout, where relatively small elements are moved (drag&drop) between columns, causing parent columns to increase/decrease in height. I must be able to prevent this behavior keeping the current layout/DOM structure.

Comment: @Alph.Dev Can you post a rough code of your layout. Maybe we can work around it.

Comment: Usually it is not needed to use Javascript in this kind of cases. And using Javascript is a signal that you are doing something wrong. Are you not able to change the layout (maybe because of seniors, or because you are using someone else's code), or do you believe you should not change the layout?

Comment: @Gockhan, The code is too complex to post, but I've just added a gif animation to the question. I believe I should not change the layout just to address this tiny rare browser bug.

Comment: @Alph.Dev Your case seems to be another problem. I can't pinpoint the exact cause but it may because the dragged element has the focus, the browser scrolls to show the whole content of it. Here is a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/t829dq4b/2/

Comment: It is unlikely to be caused by anything else than the browser sticky viewport "feature". It only occurs when the parent column meets the conditions you described, plus some other additional I noticed (like how was the bottom reached (by mouse / by code) etc. Also, focus cause would make it occur in Firefox too, but it's not the case. I'm pretty sure it's the sticky viewport browser feature.

Answer (score 1):

### for click events, use `blur`, avoid `scrollTo`

It seems like this issue is focus-related. I came across a similar bug and when the element that triggered a height change was switched to an unfocusable element, like a `div`, the screen jumping disappeared. This clearly isn't a great solution because we should be able to use buttons! It also implicates `focus` in this strange behavior. Further experimentation led to blurring the trigger element before the height change, which solves the problem without moving the viewport. I've only tried this with click events so I'm not sure if it works for drag n drop.

[codepen that showcases viewport jumping with accordions and a `blur` fix](https://codepen.io/defnotrobbie/pen/ExKLWJW)

```js
function handleClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.blur();
  // code to change height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding regarding your requirement, I have given a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/antonysuthakarj/j47xLzte/#&togetherjs=U9qo80loBA) sample.

Hope it would help to you.

If you expect something more, feel free to add comment.

Cool!

```js
$(function(){
  var height = 200;
  var pos = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
   if($(document).height() >= $(window).height()){
    var height = $('.container1').height();
    $('.container1').height(height + 20);
    pos = pos + 20;
    $(window).scrollTop(pos);
   }   
  }, 1000);
 });
```

```css
.container1 {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 min-height: 200px;
 background: #ccc;
 height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <p>11</p>
  <p>12</p>
  <p>13</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for contributing. My intent was exactly the opposite. I want browser to act as normal, keeping the same `scrollTop` when page expands. But Chrome, and maybe some others increase the `scrollTop` when content height increases (under certain conditions as pointed out by Gokhan). It's some kind of new feature that's supposed to be an improvement, but in reality it's just confusing my algorithms. I just want the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

All of your draggable elements are in a container with no auto overflow, when you drag and drop your elements the whole page scrolls due to dragging.

Instead of that do as:

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Place all your draggable elements here -->
</div>
```

set a max-height and overflow of the container class as:

```
.container {
   max-height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```

Now when you drag and drop your elements, instead of the whole page, the only container will scroll.

After implementing this solution, it will look like this.

Before dragging.
[image]

While dragging.
[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: "All of your draggable elements are in a container with no auto overflow" - that's a usability feature. I'm familiar with the approach Trello has implemented, but it has more downsides than benefits when compared.